# Heroku Application Error after pushing to app repository on git

Tags: java, git, heroku, warnings

**After pushing to app repository on git and enter to app url Heroku send me  Application Error**

[image]

**I don't know where is problem!**

**The pushing to git was normal and deploying and building app was without error**

**Here is log from server but i don't see erro**

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.7... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.1.1... done
-----> executing /app/tmp/cache/.maven/bin/mvn -B -Duser.home=/tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c -Dmaven.repo.local=/app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository  -DskipTests=true clean install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO]                                                                         
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Building warm-shore-4119 1.0-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom (4 KB at 8.1 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 KB at 363.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar (218 KB at 8071.9 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar (60 KB at 2208.4 KB/sec)
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/src/main/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ warm-shore-4119 ---
       [INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.9/maven-plugin-api-2.0.9.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.9/maven-plugin-api-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 69.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar (625 KB at 14871.5 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/target/classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ warm-shore-4119 ---
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ warm-shore-4119 ---
       [INFO] No sources to compile
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ warm-shore-4119 ---
       [INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.12.4/surefire-booter-2.12.4.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.12.4/surefire-booter-2.12.4.pom (3 KB at 141.0 KB/sec)
 [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar (33 KB at 1620.1 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Packaging webapp
       [INFO] Assembling webapp [warm-shore-4119] in [/tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/target/warm-shore-4119]
       [INFO] Processing war project
       [INFO] Copying webapp resources [/tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/src/main/webapp]
       [INFO] Webapp assembled in [86 msecs]
       [INFO] Building war: /tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/target/warm-shore-4119.war
       [INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- appassembler-maven-plugin:1.1.1:assemble (default) @ warm-shore-4119 ---
       [INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/appassembler/appassembler-model/1.1.1/appassembler-model-1.1.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/appassembler/appassembler-model/1.1.1/appassembler-model-1.1.1.pom (4 KB at 176.7 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.pom (2 KB at 78.4 KB/sec)
       [INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/java/dev/stax-utils/stax-utils/20060502/stax-utils-20060502.pom
       [INFO] Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/java/dev/stax-utils/stax-utils/20060502/stax-utils-20060502.pom (565 B at 27.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Installing /tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/target/warm-shore-4119.war to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/heroku/sample/warm-shore-4119/1.0-SNAPSHOT/warm-shore-4119-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_2311c1c33be17abc7faec57028509a4c/pom.xml to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/heroku/sample/warm-shore-4119/1.0-SNAPSHOT/warm-shore-4119-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 11.918s
       [INFO] Finished at: Sat Jan 10 10:13:25 UTC 2015
       [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/676M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 85.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v6
       https://cashconverter.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

**Server log**

```
2015-01-10T09:51:54.200595+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T09:51:54.200679+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:03:57.129262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=f62e166b-4119-4fb9-9014-ac5933a99437 fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2015-01-10T10:14:02.037333+00:00 heroku[api]: Set JAVA_OPTS config vars by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:02.037333+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:02.634087+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:02.634022+00:00 heroku[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:02.734289+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE resource by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:02.734289+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:03.050252+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:03.142403+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 35723bf by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:03.142431+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:14:08.324200+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2015-01-10T10:14:09.290022+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class launch.Main
2015-01-10T10:14:09.113796+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-01-10T10:14:10.027387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-10T10:14:10.050356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-01-10T10:14:10.050356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-01-10T10:14:13.777839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2015-01-10T10:14:14.311811+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-01-10T10:14:14.470013+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class launch.Main
2015-01-10T10:14:15.276277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-10T10:14:15.291458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-01-10T10:14:21.515247+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=b35f3f5b-bbfd-48da-b519-c0fbe39ad758 fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T10:16:30.530533+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Procfile` by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T10:16:35.600434+00:00 heroku[run.5589]: Awaiting client
2015-01-10T10:16:35.651361+00:00 heroku[run.5589]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat Procfile`
2015-01-10T10:16:36.681539+00:00 heroku[run.5589]: Process exited with status 0
2015-01-10T10:16:36.692877+00:00 heroku[run.5589]: State changed from up to complete
2015-01-10T10:16:35.873466+00:00 heroku[run.5589]: State changed from starting to up
2015-01-10T10:39:52.391028+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-01-10T10:39:57.275750+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2015-01-10T10:39:58.103272+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class launch.Main
2015-01-10T10:39:57.972901+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-01-10T10:39:58.834166+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-01-10T10:39:58.822038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-10T10:54:11.968408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=7e9ac6f7-f8b0-499b-afe1-11ff0cd1cc7b fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T11:12:07.919260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=237fe5cd-4868-4384-8460-e8314963ca07 fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T11:32:19.818919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=d9a9fdb5-2633-48e3-a3e6-51a0d13abfb8 fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T11:34:02.145176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-01-10T11:34:08.796175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2015-01-10T11:34:09.469430+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-01-10T11:34:09.600716+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class launch.Main
2015-01-10T11:34:10.296201+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-01-10T11:34:10.284538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-10T11:46:18.293578+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=433294d4-ebbd-41f8-92c1-90d5d2f3b1ce fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T11:54:41.349914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=05ea14be-f6b6-4c42-accb-46accd9df110 fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T12:22:21.008931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=53dd22b8-ac2b-48c6-b51a-d861f0ac6b1d fwd="86.56.84.183" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T12:22:22.182213+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=6149455a-0e8d-4d58-bf9f-1c2f4dada884 fwd="86.56.84.183" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T12:23:31.209484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=bf2dd553-a564-41ec-8655-bb63ca76cd61 fwd="117.216.76.9" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T12:23:37.662714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=75e323aa-1c0c-4740-93e2-797ec16e65f7 fwd="117.216.76.9" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-01-10T12:35:30+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-01-10T12:36:22+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-01-10T12:36:22.132529+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 871bcd4 by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T12:36:22.132559+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by topiciv141@gmail.com
2015-01-10T12:36:22.533659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-01-10T12:36:27.429540+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2015-01-10T12:36:28.191309+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-01-10T12:36:28.322099+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class launch.Main
2015-01-10T12:36:29.098257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-01-10T12:36:29.098684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-01-10T12:36:29.089984+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-10T12:36:33.500983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2015-01-10T12:36:34.264939+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class launch.Main
2015-01-10T12:36:34.139455+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-01-10T12:36:34.927191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-10T12:36:34.934855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-01-10T12:36:42.897046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cashconverter.herokuapp.com request_id=d767c327-1bcb-4708-adac-5ef40b919c84 fwd="46.185.15.47" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Try and `heroku logs` from the command line; what you show is only the build process

Comment: Just now i add new log to post

Comment: Most likeky it's because of 'Could not find or load main class launch.Main' in the log, you should start searching from this line

Comment: okay I understand you now try to do something